# Visual Studio Winforms Designer Errors

Tags: visual-studio-2010, devexpress

I have no idea what is going on with this. My application was working flawlessly. First off, this is Visual Studio 2010. I am creating a winforms project with multiple class library sub projects. I am using DevExpress controls also. As I said, the application worked fine. There was no issue. I was able to load my controls and have everything function properly. Then for some reason, I started getting crazy designer issues.

When double click on one of my controls to bring up the visual designer, I am greeted with an error page instead "To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved:" and then it lists a few errors stating that it cannot find controls that are contained within this control and it cannot find the control's object name:

"Could not find type 'App.SummaryControl". Please make sure that the assembly that     contains this type is referenced. If this type is a part of your development project, make sure that the project has been successfully built using settings for your current platform or Any CPU"

"The variable summaryControl1' is either undeclared or was never assigned"

These two errors exist for all controls within this control. It's a mess! When I go to debug and launch the app, it shows up correctly and I can actually see some of the controls it is displaying errors for. I have tried changing my config settings for all projects to run in Any CPU and x64. Nothing resolves these issues!

Comment: Is App.SummaryControl a control that you created? If so, is there any code in the constructor that would not work at design time? (That is, it references another object or state that is only available or valid when the entire program is running.) Another possibility is code in an event handler for App.SummaryControl's `Load` event.

Comment: I think I found what is causing it. I have a class library project in my application that handles some WCF service layer calls. This is common within our app. In here I have a manager class. This manager class is just a class file that contains methods, collections, and some service layer calls for getting, updating, and saving information. On my one control, I reference that class library (also referenced in my project). I commented out all of my code, keeping method stubs. When I try adding back in my public property for that manager class (thats in my class lib proj) it causes the issue.?

Comment: This seems just a little unusual because I feel I have done this before, and it has also worked before. Could it be because I have this set as a public property?

Comment: Could be, but maybe not. One thing you can try is to wrap any code that you suspect may be causing the problem with `if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Runtime){ // code goes here }`

Comment: I ended up commenting out all of the code, besides method stubs like I said. I have a public property that is a class in my one class library. Apparently the public property is what was breaking the control. Once I changed it to private, there was no issue. Maybe because I had get/set accessors on a public property in a class that is in a project that's being referenced and in order to reference that project the app needs to be compiled?

Comment: I'm still a little unsure of the structure of your projects/solution. I have winforms controls that reference public properties of objects in other assemblies, and they work fine in the designer. The only time there's a problem is when the instance variable behind one of these properties can't be made at design time, because in order to do so some resource that the designer can't access has to be invoked. (Reading a file, logging in to a database, etc.)

Comment: Have you tried simply restarting visual studio and rebuilding the solution? If that fails and you still can't find the problem, I think you'll need to add some code to your question.

Comment: I did everything. I was able to figure it out. I have my main project. OpApp. Then I have some Lib projects, TransactionsLib, EmployeesLib, etc. In my OpApp I have references to the 2 libraries. The libraries are basically calls to our WCF service and contain references to the appropriate DLL files. In one of my controls in OpApp I have a form with a tab control. In one of the tab controls there is a control that contains a public property of an object that lives in my TransactionsLib. I am imagining this breaks on design time because the app would need to be compiled.